# How to compute: $\int_0^1\frac{(1-t^2)^s}{2^{-s}(1-t^2)^s+ t^s}\frac{dt}{1+t^2} $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am looking for the closed expresion of the following integral

$$I_s=\int_0^1\frac{(1-t^2)^s}{2^{-s}(1-t^2)^s+ t^s}\frac{dt}{1+t^2} $$

I have proved already that $I_s$ exists for any $s\in \Bbb R.$ For $s=0$ I got

$$I_0=\frac{\pi}{8}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using changing variables $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ then
$dt=\frac{1}{2}(1+\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}})dx=\frac{1}{2}(1+t^2)dx,$
so  $$I_s=\int_0^1\frac{(1-t^2)^s}{2^{-s}(1-t^2)^s+ t^s}\frac{dt}{1+t^2} =2^{s-1}\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+(\frac{2t}{1-t^2})^s}\frac{2dt}{(1+t^2)}\\=2^{s-1}\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{s} x} \,dx =\color{red}{2^{s-3}\pi}$$
the last integral which can be calculated as per the method shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571802/is-there-a-closed-form-for-the-integral-int-0-pi-2-frac-1-1-tans-x/2571805?noredirect=1#comment5307954_2571805).